# Postgres.app security on a Mac?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm wondering if there are any security concerns with installing PostgreSQL on a Mac using the app?

https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

I had a look at the data folder and it's owned by me rather than the best practice which I believe is to create a user just for postgres and then install it with that user. But with the app, you are pretty much stuck with installing it as yourself!

Comment: Is this just for a local dev environment or are other machines going to connect to this database?

Comment: Other machines will connect. All will be on the same network and all will have internet access.

Comment: Why are you running a server on what seems to be a client machine?

Comment: I've got dual booting PCs that will connect to it. I can't have a server on a dual booting machine. The Mac OS stands alone. Not ideal, but I'm working with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two possible scenarios: The server will only ever be reachable via the local network, or it will be reachable via the internet by a proxy application (e.g. a web service connecting to the database)

#### Internal Network Only

In this case, running the server as your local user is fine. It's not ideal, but it's not the end of the world either. It assumes that you control the devices in your local network, and can be reasonably certain that none of them are compromised.

If one of your local home devices is compromised, then you got bigger problems to deal with than which user your Prostrgres server is rnning under.

#### Reachable by Internet

For example, your Postgres server is running on your Mac, together with a web application, which is accessible from the internet, and the web application is accessing the Postgres server.

In this case, the risk is quite a bit higher. In your case, I would invest in what I call a "low-end home server". A [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) would be a good choice, as it has enough power to act as a low-end home server, while still costing less than 100 USD and consuming very little power. You can, of course, also do a DIY solution with mode modular hardware, but that'll cost more and can be a hassle.

Since a low-end home server would just run a Linux distro of your choice, you can just set it up like you would any other server, with separate users per server process.

Comment: Yes, I want to only allow access from the internal network devices only. Thanks I'll proceed without reinstalling the database.